# How to deny users from creating subdirectories?

Tags: permissions

Is there a possibility to deny users from creating directories in a given directory?

Comment: Not without also prevent the creation of files.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78191/prevent-creating-directories-but-allow-creating-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to revoke write permissions for the directory. It can be done by

```
chmod -w /path/to/dir
```

The user will not be able to create files or directories in the directory.

But I do not see a simple way to allow users to create files and do not allow to create directories.

There can be a workaround with a script using `inotify` that will detect creation of directories and doing something, like removing them, etc.

Another option is to revoke permissions from `mkdir`. In this case the user will not be able to create any directories.

And also there is another [very hacky way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170287/115385)

Comment: Aside: if I find I can't call `mkdir`, I'll just [call `cp -r` instead](http://serverfault.com/a/520585/244015). I'm sure other ways exist, even if I don't have Python or something really obvious available.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That's correct. I just gave very general ideas.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux everything is a file. If you prevent the creation of directories, you also prevent the creation of normal files. And you definitely do not want that, as I gather from your comment.

Comment: I really tried, but I don't understand what you're trying to say. :D

Comment: @David: What A.B. is trying to tell you is: is you prevent users from creating directories, you will also prevent yours from creating files...  Creating files but not creating directories is currently impossible with the `ext4 ` file system...

Comment: That comment was from before the answer was edited, but thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove write permissions on that directory for groups. I'd guess

```
$ sudo chown root:user /path/to/dir
$ sudo chmod 755 /path/to/dir
```

Creating files is also no longer possible then, though.